# How to change a button to a splitbutton?

Tags: php, extjs

I have a button defined as xtype: button,

On click a record, I need to change the xtype to Splitbutton and add a menu to it according to the data returned from database.

How can this be done?

I've tried:

```
Ext.GetCmp(buttonid).xtype = 'splitbutton'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just replace the button with a splitbutton.

Comment: make a splitbutton, hide it.  when you click the record, hide the first button, show the splitbutton.

Comment: How brilliant, Thank you so much @Snowburnt , I took you advice and it works well!